# How can I make sure mod_rewrite is enabled using SALT provisioning

Tags: vagrant, provisioning, salt-stack

I am using SALT provisioning to create my vagrant box.

In my apache2.sls I have

```
apache2:
  pkg:
    - installed
  service:
    - running
```

How can I make sure mod_rewrite is enabled?

Thank you so much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to just enable mod_rewrite, try something like this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite:
  cmd.run:
    - unless: test -f /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
    - require:
      - pkg: apache2

apache2:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: apache2
  service.running:
    - name: apache2
    - require:
      - pkg: apache2
    - watch:
      - cmd: sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

This should install the package, then run the script (since the service requires both the cmd and the pkg), and then it will watch to restart the service once the script has been run. If it doesn't work for you, feel free to join us in the #salt irc and we'll get it figured out!